# Jquery mouseout triggers when cursor is still over the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance to all willing to help. My riddle is the mouseout effect in jQuery - I'm trying to get build a function that would move an element up and down inside the container, indefinitely. When hovered, the moving should stop and stay stopped until the cursor leaves the element completely. What happens though, is that mouseover event triggers all right, however, the mouseleave event is triggered right after, when the cursor is still over the element, so the animation breaks.

Here's simple HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="element">Some text</div>
  <div class="element">Some other text</div>
  <div class="element">Some more text</div>
</div>
```

The moving element is positioned absolutely by javascript over the top element and moves down and up, here's the example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aytech/LMkae/9/)

Did anyone else have to deal with this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pull your mouseenter and mouseout events outside of your animate function. Everytime you call the animate function you are adding another mouse event to each element. This is causing it to call your animate function multiple times when you mouse out.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/2TnP5/), I added a counter to see how many times animate function is being called.

```
var counter = 0;
function animate(el, dir) {
   $("#count").val(counter);
   counter++;
```

Mouse over and out a couple times and you can see that it's compounding the animate calls every time you mouse out.

Comment: All right, I moved the hover triggers out of the animate function, and it indeed stopped the multiple function calls, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aytech/LMkae/15/) updated. However the mouseout effect is still there - when I hover the mouse over the element, mouseover triggers, and the mouseout event is triggered right after, even though the cursor is still over the element. I tried to bind the hover event, but still no olove... :(

Comment: I think whats happening is when the u mouse enter a div.element your bringing the pointer element right on top of the other div making u mouse out because your mouse is now on the pointer and not the div.element.  Also if you wait till the pointer gets to the bottom and hover the last element and then don't move the mouse both mouse enter and mouseout will not fire because you were mouse entering the pointer

Comment: omg, you're so right now, i completely forgot I'm placing an element over the one being hovered over. Of course the mouseout event should be attached to the moving div. I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aytech/LMkae/17/) and it works. Issue is solved now, thanks Matt, appreciated.
By the way, what do you think of the way it's done? Is it ok or could it be done better? I'm not an UI coder, just trying my hand in it ... :)

Comment: I like the way your doing it, the animation of it moving looks good. The only other way i could think of at the moment would be to just change the border color in a interval but that wouldn't have the cool animation of it going up and down.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I planned to do at the beginning, but thought that a moving element would look nicer than just changing the element class or smth like that.
Anyways, the thing seems to be working now, there were some glitches with hover effect, I just had to clear the timeout every time an event fires. 
Thanks for the advice, Matt, I would've definitely given your answer a vote, but I'm a newby here, they say I can't do that yet :(